# Does zookeeper need to be stopped when cleaning old snapshots using zkCleanup.sh script?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

Does zookeeper need to be stopped before deleting old snapshots using zkCleanup.sh script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

According to [How to purge old zookeeper directory files](https://community.hortonworks.com/content/supportkb/48795/how-to-purge-old-zookeeper-directory-files.html) by HortonWorks
and [Maintaining a ZooKeeper Server](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/cdh_ig_zookeeper_server_maintain.html) by Cloudera neither mention the need to stop ZooKeeper in order to purge old snapshots.

Since HortonWorks & Cloudera represent most of the commercial installations of Hadoop, I'd treat this as a reliable source of truth.